# Characterisation of degenerated critical point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}$ be a function of $C^2$.

For a critical point $x_0\in\Bbb{R}^n$ with $\det(H_f(x_0))\neq 0$ we can do the characterisation based on the Hessian Matrix $H_f(x_0)$:

- If all eigenvalues are $>0$, then $x_0$ is a local minimum.
- If all eigenvalues are $<0$, then $x_0$ is a local maximum.
- If there are both eigenvalues $<0$ and eigenvalues $>0$, then $x_0$ is a saddle point.

I tried to do a similar case distinction for a degenerated critical point $x_0\in\Bbb{R}^n$ (so $\det(H_f(x_0)) = 0$).

Are the following lines true?

Characterisation based on the non-zero eigenvalues of the Hessian Matrix $H_f(x_0)$:

- If all non-zero eigenvalues are $>0$, then $x_0$ is either a local minimum or a saddle point.
- If all non-zero eigenvalues are $<0$, then $x_0$ is either a local maximum or a saddle point.
- If there are non-zero eigenvalues $>0$ and non-zero eigenvalues $<0$, then $x_0$ is a saddle point.
- If all eigenvalues are $0$, then $x_0$ is either a local minimum, a local maximum or a saddle point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The only thing you can say *for sure* is:

- if there are positive eigenvalues, the critical point cannot be a local maximum;
- if there are negative eigenvalues, the critical point cannot be a local minimum.

The way I like to think about the "second derivative test" is in terms of Taylor expansion of $f(x_0 + t \delta x)$ for different directions $\delta x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. If $\delta x$ is in the kernel of the Hessian, all information about whether $g(t) = f(x_0 + t\delta x)$ increases or decreases must come from higher-order terms.

As a simple counterexample to your first claim, consider for instance
$$f(x) = -x^4$$
at $x=0$; all of its (nonexistent) nonzero Hessian eigenvalues are positive, but it's not a local minimum.

Comment: Thank you very much. What about the following claim:  If $\det(H_f(x_0)) = 0$ and the Hessian matrix has at least one positive eigenvalue and at least one negative eigenvalue, then $x_0$ is a saddle point.

Comment: @ms0 Yes, this is true. You can prove it by Taylor expanding $f(x_0 + t \delta x)$ for $\delta x$ the eigenvectors with positive and negative eigenvalue.